# Unable to connect to SharePoint Online with CAML Builder

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

I have U2UCamlBuilder.exe with this I can connect to local sites and build the queries as per requirement.

But I'm unable to connect to the online site, once I have connected I can see only **-Lists**

No lists or any other libraries are seen.

How can I connect to SharePoint Online and build the queries?

[image]

Comment: an alternative is the BIWUG CAML Designer that can connect to SPO

Comment: Some one have given this 
 http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com  reference for the same.

Comment: When you connect, do you indicate "Credentials of the current user" or "Custom credentials" ?

Comment: Yes, I have entered the credentials and after that I seen the above window.